# CAMBIAR UNA FILA DE COLOR EN WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

soy nuevo en WPF, alguien sabe como puedo cambiar el color de una fila en un datagrid WPF, ya que no encuentro aun como hacerlo.

la idea es que al ir eliminando filas de mi data grid estos queden de color rojo, para identificar cuales fueron los que se borraron.

alguna idea gracias de antemano

Comment: Confírmame: lo que quieres es que se marque en rojo pero SIN que desaparezca de la lista? porque así lo entiendo.. Si eres nuevo supongo que no estás usando el patrón MVVM o si? eso es esencial saberlo para darte una respuesta correcta.

Comment: es correcto no quiero que desaparesca solo marcarlo o pintar la fila de rojo para que se sepa que este fue el que se elimino, y como no entendi muy bien el MVVM estoy ocupandolo con el codebehid c#, ojala puedas ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modificas el style the las celdas de tu data grid, a dicho style le agregas un [`DataTrigger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2) (o [`MultiDataTrigger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2) segun sea el caso) donde valides alguna propiedad del `DataContext` de la celda.

Tomando como ejemplo que tu `DataGrid` mostrara Productos, en tu clase `Producto` deberias de tener una propiedad que se llame `EstaBorrado`.

*Edicion*: `INotifyPropertyChanged` Notificara a la GUI que la propiedad ha cambiado y esta actualizara su valor para el usuario.

```
public class Producto: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool estaBorrado;
    private string nombre;

    public string Nombre 
    {
        get
        {
            return nombre;
        } 
        set
        {
            if(nombre == value) return;

            nombre = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Nombre");
        }
    }

    public bool EstaBorrado 
    {
        get
        {
            return estaBorrado;
        } 
        set
        {
            if(estaBorrado == value) return;

            estaBorrado = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EstaBorrado");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Tu Style quedaria algo asi:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EstaBorrado}" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Para que funcione se debe implementar InotifyPropertyChanged en la propiedad EstadoBorrado, y dado que hace referencia a la fila, el TargetType del Style debería ser DataGridRow.

Comment: cierto, olvide ese pequeño detalle, gracias por mencioarlo

Comment: hola , muchas gracias la idea del xaml, me funciono a la perfeccion, solo cuando cambia de color todas las celdas del datagrid, al final no los ajusta queda de color original de la fila, no eh podido dar con esa parte

Comment: como? te sigue cambiando de color todos lo renglones del grid?

Answer (score 1):

Si eres nuevo y no estás usando el patrón MVVM, puedes capturar el evento PreviewKeyDown y cambiarlo desde ahí. Sería algo así:

En el XML:

En el codebehind:

```
 private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ContainerFromIndex(grid.SelectedIndex);

                row.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: hola basandome en el comentario, y revisando la estructura del proyecto que tengo, agregue las siguientes lineas

Comment: private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {    Scanned Result = new Scanned(); 
            Result = (Scanned)e.Row.Item;
            if(Result != null)
            {   if (Result.Enable == false)
                {  e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue); }
            }else  {
                return; }
        }      pero esta cambiando todas las filas de color con el scroll

Comment: tendras alguna idea? qu eme pueda orientar

Comment: En tu comentario utilizas el evento LoadingRow, el cual salta justo después de que un objeto DataGridRow sea instanciado para permitirte realizar cambios en la fila antes de que sea utilizada (puedes visitar este enlace: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: No creo que sea el evento más apropiado para tus necesidades, por lo que deduzco de tu comentario, lo que quieres no es que la fila se marque en rojo tras ser eliminada por el usuario, si no marcar en distinto color aquellas donde la propiedad Enabled del source de la fila (que parece ser de tipo Scanned) sea false. Siempre puedes usar un datatemplate para este caso. Hazme saber si es esto lo que necesitas y si es así edito mi respuesta.